# RX threadding issues in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, system.reactive

I have some simple code:

```
var timer =  Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp();

 //timer.Subscribe(x => timerTb.Text = x.Value.ToString());
 timer.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x.Value));
```

And a textbox on the view called timerTb. I am trying to get the commented out line to work without it shouting about marshalling issues.

From what i can find out i should be using `timer.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(...`
But i do not have access to this method, nor do i have access to the CoreDispatcherScheduler dispite referencing "System.Reactive.Linq;"

I am running RX 2.0.20304.0

Any ideas?

Comment: The value of Rx rapidly disappears when you use it to run code that's fundamentally thread-unsafe.  At least as posted, there's no good reason to not use a DispatcherTimer instead.

Comment: I am just trying to reproduce some of the things done 38 mins into this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Rx-Updat-NET-45-Async-WinRT

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working.

Silly rookie mistake CoreDispatcherScheduler was in : System.Reactive.Windows.Threading

Once i referenced that i got ObserveOnDispatcher() and this worked:

```
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp();

timer.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(x => timerTb.Text = x.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your timer on the UI thread:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), CoreDispatcherScheduler.Instance)
    .Timestamp();
```